# goroutine leak with buffered channel in Go

Tags: go

Th following codes is in **The Go Programming Language**

```
func mirroredQuery() string {
    responses := make(chan string, 3)
    go func() { responses <- request("asia.gopl.io") }()
    go func() { responses <- request("europe.gopl.io") }()
    go func() { responses <- request("americas.gopl.io") }()
    return <-responses // return the quickest response
}

func request(hostname string) (response string) { /* ... */ }
```

And book says

> Had we used an unbuffered channel, the two slower
>   goroutines would have gotten stuck trying to send their responses
>   on a channel from which no goroutine will ever receive . This situation, called a goroutine leak, would be a bug . Unlike garbage
>   variables, leaked goroutines are not automatically collec ted, so
>   it is important to make sure that goroutines terminate themselves
>   when no longer needed.

And the **question** is why this situation will cause a `goroutine` leak.In my idea, the buffered channel's `cap` is 3, and 3 `goroutines` will send their requests and exit immediately which will not cause the leak.

Answer (score 4):

The code shown does not cause a leak.

As the paragraph states:

> *Had we used* an unbuffered channel

Meaning: **if** we had used an unbuffered channel...

So only if the channel was unbuffered the leak would occur.

Comment: @eugenjoy in case of buffered channel why will the two slower goroutines not try to send their responses to the channel? There can be a case in which before one of the goroutine has sent its request, a response is received to this "<-responses"

Comment: @rnjai : the slower goroutines will indeed try to send the responses to the channel. No one will actually read those responses, but that is not a problem cause the channel has a buffer size of 3, so responses can be accomodated in the buffer so the goroutines will not block.

Comment: yes, @eugenioy the goroutines will definitely not block, but there will certainly be a scope of goroutine leak since sending to a channel without receiver leads to a leak - https://play.golang.org/p/vMKwqoACGfT

Comment: hi @rnjai, I don't think your test is correct.. try changing your cycle to run it 100 times and take a look at the output.. number of goroutines stay stable and does not grow over time: https://play.golang.org/p/2DwtFkey53l